# Data Validation - Two Cells Cannot Have the Same Value

Tags: microsoft-excel, data-validation

Cell C2 and Cell G2 cannot both be greater than 0 at the same time. 
If C2 or G2 has greater than 0 on it's own that's fine.

I have an error message set up saying these two cells cannot both, at the same time, have numbers greater than 0. My problem is getting the correct custom formula. In order that the error message does not show up when one cell has a value greater than 0 on its own.

Comment: @ScottCraner Thank you very much. Sadly I spent 4 hours on my own watching videos and reading things to figure this out, before posting a question. You are amazing, thank you for your kindness.

Comment: Consider using conditional formatting if you want to highlight the cells with colours

Answer (score 2):

You want False to happen when both are greater than 0:

```
=NOT(AND(C2>0,G2>0))
```

When one or both are less than or equal to `0` the AND will return `FALSE` and `TRUE` if both are greater than `0`.

The NOT returns the opposite.